# ImportError: cannot import name 'Input' from 'keras.engine'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am getting import error for the 'Input' model. Please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yy6W0.png)

[This is what I get after running the previous code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwWs1.png)

What should I do?

I even tried upgrading the keras and tensorflow by this code =
`your text`!pip install tensorflow==2.1
`your text`!pip install keras==2.3.1

I even tried these code=
`your text`from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input Layer

Comment: Please add code and errors as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

You are installing the older tensorflow and keras version. This is always recommended to install the latest tensorflow version 2.12 (`pip install tensorflow==2.12`) with python 3.10 in your system to have better features and functionalities availability. Please have a look at this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#step-by-step_instructions) page for the steps.

Also, you need to use below code to import [input layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Input).

```
from tensorflow.keras import Input
```